# How to set user name and group name in IAM using CloudFormation?

Tags: aws-cloudformation, amazon-iam

I created a CloudFormation template and I wanted to create IAM user, to do that I used this JSON string:

```
"CFNUser" : {
  "Type" : "AWS::IAM::User",
  "Properties" : {
    "LoginProfile": {
      "Password": { "Ref" : "AdminPassword" }
    }
  }
},
```

Then for group I used this:

```
"CFNUserGroup" : {
  "Type" : "AWS::IAM::Group"
},
```

After creating the stack, I got the following:

> user name - IAMUsers-CFNUser-E1BT342YK7G6
>
> group name - IAMUsers-CFNUserGroup-1UBUBRYALTIMI

So my question is, how can I set the user name here? same goes for the group name?

Answer (score 20):

After talking with one of the AWS support, at this time of writing, it is not possible to specify your own username and group name in IAM using CloudFormation template :-(

Maybe there's a reason why they do not allow user to do this...anyway it's good thing that I have answer to this question and I will be glad if someone find this useful.

Comment: It's not very pretty, but I think it's to ensure uniqueness when multiple CloudFormation stacks are used. You can change the resource name "CFNUserGroup" to any string you like, but it would be nice if the console gave more space to the name at least.

Answer (score 4):

Amazon has added support from 20th July 2016. 
https://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/whats-new/2016/07/aws-cloudformation-adds-support-for-aws-iot-and-additional-updates/

```
{
  "Type": "AWS::IAM::User",
  "Properties": {
    "Groups": [ String, ... ],
    "LoginProfile": LoginProfile Type,
    "ManagedPolicyArns": [ String, ... ],
    "Path": String,
    "Policies": [ Policies, ... ],
    "UserName": String
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

For groups, it's a GroupName property:

```html
    "CFNUserGroup" : {
       "Type" : "AWS::IAM::Group",
       "Properties": {
          "GroupName": "My_CFN_User_Group"
        }
     }
```